# Remove array index based on date

Tags: php, arrays, symfony

I am working with Symfony framework and I have a Controller whose job is to fetch the RSS feeds.

Once I have the fetched feeds in a set of array, I would like to remove those feeds whose `date` is greater than the date I provide.

So this is the array of object that I get when I fetch the feeds

```
Array
(
    [0] => AppBundle\Entity\Rss Object
        (
            [id:AppBundle\Entity\Rss:private] => 
            [feedItemTitle:AppBundle\Entity\Rss:private] => Project Manager, Investments Business Management - Prudential - Madison, NJ
            [feedItemDescription:AppBundle\Entity\Rss:private] => Globally, PREI has offices in Munich, Frankfurt, London, Paris, Luxembourg, Singapore, Seoul, Tokyo, Sydney, and Mexico City....

            From Prudential - 30 Jul 2015 20:00:31 GMT
            -  View all Madison jobs
            [feedItemLink:AppBundle\Entity\Rss:private] => http://www.indeed.com/job/Project-Manager-at-Prudential-in-Madison,-NJ-27eedeae3104d1be
            [feedItemPubDate:AppBundle\Entity\Rss:private] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2015-07-30 20:00:31.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 1
                    [timezone] => +00:00
                )

        )

    [1] => AppBundle\Entity\Rss Object
        (
            [id:AppBundle\Entity\Rss:private] => 
            [feedItemTitle:AppBundle\Entity\Rss:private] => Client Services Specialist - Prudential - Madison, NJ
            [feedItemDescription:AppBundle\Entity\Rss:private] => Globally, PREI has offices in Munich, Frankfurt, London, Paris, Luxembourg, Singapore, Seoul, Tokyo, Sydney, and Mexico City....

            From Prudential - 03 Aug 2015 19:59:34 GMT
            -  View all Madison jobs
            [feedItemLink:AppBundle\Entity\Rss:private] => http://www.indeed.com/job/Client-Service-Specialist-at-Prudential-in-Madison,-NJ-51ad596876a01466
            [feedItemPubDate:AppBundle\Entity\Rss:private] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2015-08-03 19:59:34.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 1
                    [timezone] => +00:00
                )

        )

    [2] => AppBundle\Entity\Rss Object
        (
            [id:AppBundle\Entity\Rss:private] => 
            [feedItemTitle:AppBundle\Entity\Rss:private] => Manager, Client Services - Prudential - Madison, NJ
            [feedItemDescription:AppBundle\Entity\Rss:private] => Globally, PREI has offices in Munich, Frankfurt, London, Paris, Luxembourg, Singapore, Seoul, Tokyo, Sydney, and Mexico City....

            From Prudential - 03 Aug 2015 19:59:32 GMT
            -  View all Madison jobs
            [feedItemLink:AppBundle\Entity\Rss:private] => http://www.indeed.com/job/Manager-at-Prudential-in-Madison,-NJ-c0452d58384711e7
            [feedItemPubDate:AppBundle\Entity\Rss:private] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2015-08-03 19:59:32.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 1
                    [timezone] => +00:00
                )

        )

    [3] => AppBundle\Entity\Rss Object
        (
            [id:AppBundle\Entity\Rss:private] => 
            [feedItemTitle:AppBundle\Entity\Rss:private] => Technical Sales Representative, Cell Culture Products - STEMCELL Technologies Inc - United States
            [feedItemDescription:AppBundle\Entity\Rss:private] => We create novel, useful, standardized products of unfailing quality and deliver them to more than 70 countries via our many regional offices plus distribution...

            From STEMCELL Technologies Inc - 01 Aug 2015 01:16:36 GMT
            -  View all  jobs
            [feedItemLink:AppBundle\Entity\Rss:private] => http://www.indeed.com/job/Technical-Sales-Representative-at-STEMCELL-Technologies-in-United-States-f4c10a0e10852686
            [feedItemPubDate:AppBundle\Entity\Rss:private] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2015-08-01 01:16:36.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 1
                    [timezone] => +00:00
                )

        )

    [4] => AppBundle\Entity\Rss Object
        (
            [id:AppBundle\Entity\Rss:private] => 
            [feedItemTitle:AppBundle\Entity\Rss:private] => Technical Sales Representative, Cell Separation Products - STEMCELL Technologies Inc - United States
            [feedItemDescription:AppBundle\Entity\Rss:private] => We create novel, useful, standardized products of unfailing quality and deliver them to more than 70 countries via our many regional offices plus distribution...

            From STEMCELL Technologies Inc - 31 Jul 2015 01:13:35 GMT
            -  View all  jobs
            [feedItemLink:AppBundle\Entity\Rss:private] => http://www.indeed.com/job/Technical-Sales-Representative-at-STEMCELL-Technologies-in-United-States-b8c62120268afb55
            [feedItemPubDate:AppBundle\Entity\Rss:private] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2015-07-31 01:13:35.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 1
                    [timezone] => +00:00
                )

        )

    [5] => AppBundle\Entity\Rss Object
        (
            [id:AppBundle\Entity\Rss:private] => 
            [feedItemTitle:AppBundle\Entity\Rss:private] => Accounting Intern - Code Corp - Draper, UT
            [feedItemDescription:AppBundle\Entity\Rss:private] => Would love someone that is interested in International Accounting processes because this position will work with our China, Singapore & Europe office....

            From Code Corp - 31 Jul 2015 21:13:43 GMT
            -  View all Draper jobs
            [feedItemLink:AppBundle\Entity\Rss:private] => http://www.indeed.com/job/Accounting-Intern-at-Code-in-Draper,-UT-0e0aca45e988cc89
            [feedItemPubDate:AppBundle\Entity\Rss:private] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2015-07-31 21:13:43.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 1
                    [timezone] => +00:00
                )

        )   
)
```

As you will notice `date` in above array.

I am passing the above array and date (not the `date` from an array above but the `$date` that i would like to match the array date with to exclude the feed or not) in a parameter to a function below

```
public function isValid($feed, $date)
{
    foreach ($feed as $item) {

        if ($item->getfeedItemPubDate()->date < $date) {
            echo $item->getfeedItemPubDate()->date;
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }

}
```

I am able to get the list of feeds whose `date` from array are smaller than `$date` but what I am stuck at is how to remove those feeds from the array ? and then pass back the new set of array back to the controller.

Comment: `foreach ($feed as $key =>$item) ` then when condition it true `unset($feed[$key]);`

Comment: Many thanks @splash58 it worked. Would you like to add that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I did it. Glad to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove array item by unset function. To know key of that item change a little foreach loop. As so, for example

```
public function isValid($feed, $date)
{
    foreach ($feed as $key => $item) 
        if ($item->getfeedItemPubDate()->date < $date)
            unset ($feed[$key]);   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function to which you provide a callback function, in your case something like

```
$feed = array_filter($feed, function($item) use($date) {
     return ($item->getfeedItemPubDate()->date < $date);
});
```

where `$date` is a variable you set before

Comment: is this supposed to go inside the `foreach` loop?

Comment: No, thats the magic of `array_filter`, it loops internally and thus is much more efficient. Just assign the result to an array or even back into `$feed`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public function isValid($feed, $date)
{
foreach ($feed as $item) {

    if (strtotime($item->getfeedItemPubDate()->date) < strtotime($date)) {
        echo $item->getfeedItemPubDate()->date;
        echo "<br>";
    }
}

}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.